# How to route audio through Apple device's internal speakers, avoiding headphones?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, speaker

I'm using the `kAudioSessionPoperty_AudioRoute` and setting it to `kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRouteSpeaker`. I want the output audio to be routed through internal speakers only but when I insert headphones it gets routed through that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);

UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```